# Is $\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{v'}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ true, where $v$ and $x$ are column vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

Suppose $\mathbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \end{pmatrix}$ are column vectors.

It is clear that (correct me if wrong):
$$\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial v_n}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial v_n}{\partial x_2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_k} & \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_k} & \dots & \frac{\partial v_n}{\partial x_k} \\
\end{pmatrix}_{k\times n}$$

But what about transposed $\mathbf{v}$ ?

Is $\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{v'}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ ?

Comment: I believe the Jacobian as defined does not care whether $v$ is a column or a row vector, so I expect those would be equal.

Comment: What is $v'$ in your question ?

Comment: @nmasanta $v'$ is the transpose of the vector $v$.

Comment: You should have to mentioned it clearly in your question @Digitallis